# Using K-means for hierarchy clustering, a good approach?

Tags: clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset and I would like to see how the dataset is organized via a hierarchy.

I have thought of using a divisive method as follows:

```
1. Cluster the data into 2 classes using K-means (k=2)
2. Cluster Each of the 2 classes using K-means (with k=2) to create a total of 4 classes
3. And so on,
```

Would this be a good approach to constructing a dendogram for my data?

Another approach I have considered was

```
1. Create 15 clusters of my data
2. Cluster the 15 centroids into 5 classes
3. Cluster the 5 centroids into 2 classes
```

Then we can see a formed hierarchy for my data. Is this approach better?

Comment: why 15, 5 and 2? I personally prefer clustering into n-1 clusters, n-2, n-3 and so on... But we don't know enough about your data.

Comment: Hey Expecto, I just said those k values just for example. I would definitely do it the way you suggested.

Comment: This is generally not a good idea. Consider the data are really comprised of 3 clusters. How will you catch them three with your 2-then-each-in-2 k-means strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward approach is to use the hierarchical clustering [see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) and `hclust` function in R. This allows to form hierarchy as well as to see the influence of the different linkages and distance metrics. Also, it is worth noting that there are many good alternatives to kmeans, see for example [mclust package](http://www.stat.washington.edu/mclust/)

Comment: I'm actually using Python! Would you happen to know of a method such as `hclust` available in packages such as scikit-learn?

Comment: @AA In Python: [scipy.cluster.hierarchy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html) ([example1](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/herrfz/dataanalysis/blob/master/week3/hierarchical_clustering.ipynb), [example2](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/herrfz/dataanalysis/blob/master/week4/clustering_example.ipynb)). Or to be more precise, use [scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) with `method='centroid'`, to get "hierarchical k-means" (though, `'average'` and `'weighted'` may by similar).

Comment: Thanks for your help! however i seem to get `ValueError: Valid methods when the raw observations are omitted are 'single', 'complete', 'weighted', and 'average'.` when I use centroid as the method

Comment: I am afraid I can't help you with python, but if you google "hierarchical clustering python", you will get many results to start with.

Comment: @AA Did you look at the examples? You also need to specify distance. In any case, show me the lines of code that are not working (otherwise I will be not possible to 'debug' it).

Comment: It turns out that centroid isn't actually a valid keyword

Comment: @AA Strange - it is in the documentation. Either you have some old version of SciPy, or something else is wrong with the code
(BTW: Could you please use `@PiotrMigdal`, otherwise I may miss it.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it may be better and easier to use a method/tool that is hierarchical than manually doing this yourself.

A good example of this is the tree library in R. Check out Jeffrey Leek's lesson on [Predicting with trees](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdUVUINpFmI).

Here's a good R code example from Dr. Leek's lesson:

```
data(iris)
install.packages('tree')
library(tree)
tree1 <- tree(Species ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width, data=iris)
plot(tree1)
text(tree1)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This appears decision trees, I am really looking for a clustering method

Comment: Oops you're right. I didn't look at it closely enough. I am confusing this with hclust's dendrogram.
The correct link for hierarchical clustering is here: https://github.com/jtleek/dataanalysis/blob/master/week3/004hierachicalClustering/index.md
And the video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zygVdmlS-YA